# Best practices to obtain small quantity of sealed solution without oxidising entire solution?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, experimental-chemistry

I'm ordering liquid based chemicals which only come in large bulk quantities. These solutions have a shelf life of approximately 2 years unopened, but 2 - 3 weeks once opened and oxidation kicks in. To put things into perspective, they come in 5 litre bottles to dilute to 50 litres but I only require 100ml per use. So going through 5 litres in 2 - 3 weeks is not realistic whatsoever.

So this got me thinking if there is a way I could obtain small quantities of a solution without at all exposing the entire solution to the atmosphere? The first thing that comes to mind is to obtain the solution within a vacuum chamber, then finding a way to vacuum seal the bottle back up.

Would that be a good practice or are there better ways to work around this problem?

Comment: In a lab environment this would be done by sealing the 5L bottle with a septum under a dry nitrogen atmosphere. To extract solution you would use a syringe and needle through the septum with a second needle supplying nitrogen into the 5L bottle. Harder to do this at home!

Comment: A simple solution would be to use a glove bag (these are readily available from chemical suppliers) flushed with an inert gas like nitrogen to transfer the solutions from the large bottle into a number of small 100mL sealable bottles.

Comment: You might also join a photo hobbyist group, perhaps through a nearby school, to share the cost of chemicals. Learning together is more fun, too. Sorry, this is not a technical answer.

Comment: Could an electricity based induction sealer be used within the inert atmosphere glove box to seal a foil liner over the smaller bottles?

Comment: @srb633 This is possible (because all what the device does, is providing heat locally, like a pair of curling irons).  For a stationary installation, you e.g., pass the power cord across one of the feedthroughs like for a balance (an example with a laminator is shown on fig. 12 [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/225648774_Development_of_near_hermetic_siliconglass_cavities_for_packaging_of_integrated_lithium_micro_batteries)).